# HP Pavilion 15 aw002la issues UBUNTU 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, 16.04, battery, hp-pavilion

Hi I've bought a HP Pavilion 15 aw002la running windows 10, immediately I downloaded ubuntu 16.04, and installed from pendrive. From the beginning I noticed that the wifi was unstable and when I clicked the touchpad the pointer suddenly appeared at the bottom of the screen. 
Additionally the battery lasts only 1:30 hours while on Windows lasts 4 to 5 hours
I tried to fix it by installing the updates from "Details" in Configuration, but it all went wrong and now the ubuntu software center does not execute and I can't install anything.

I've not installed any driver from ubuntu.
These are the specifications of my laptop:

**HP PAVILION 15 aw00LA**

- RAM: 16GB
- CPU: AMD Quad-Core A10-9600P
- Storage: 1TB
- GPU: AMD Radeon™ R7 M440
- WLAN:802.11b/g/n

Please, can someone help me?
If some more information is needed to help me, just ask for it.

Note: Ubuntu is installed alongside Windows 10

```
$ lspci -knn

00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1576]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:81fe]

00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Carrizo [1002:9874] (rev ca)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Carrizo [103c:81fe]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu

00:01.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio [1002:9840]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Kabini HDMI/DP Audio [103c:81fe]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:157b]
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD

00:02.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:157c]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:157c]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:157c]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:03.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:157b]

00:03.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:157c]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:08.0 Encryption controller [1080]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1578]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:81fe]

00:09.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:157d]

00:09.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:157a]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:81fe]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:10.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller [1022:7914] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company FCH USB XHCI Controller [103c:81fe]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:11.0 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1022:7901] (rev 49)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [103c:81fe]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:12.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller [1022:7908] (rev 49)
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller [1022:7908]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:790b] (rev 4a)
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:790b]
    Kernel driver in use: piix4_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_piix4

00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:790e] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:790e]

00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1570]

00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1571]

00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1572]
    Kernel modules: amd64_edac_mod

00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1573]
    Kernel driver in use: k10temp
    Kernel modules: k10temp

00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1574]
    Kernel driver in use: fam15h_power
    Kernel modules: fam15h_power

00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1575]

01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5229] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Realtek PCIE CardReader
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader [103c:81fe]
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    DeviceName: Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:81fe]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    DeviceName: Realtek RTL8723BE 802.11b/g/n Wi-Fi + BT 4.0 Combo Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:81c1]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be

04:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265] [1002:6900] (rev ff)
    DeviceName: AMD Radeon (TM) R7 440M
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -knn`.

Comment: Done, I think sorry I'm new on Ubuntu @AndroidDev